# Error when trying to retrieve a single entity

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I've been playing around with Google Cloud Endpoints for the past few days (aiming to hook it up with AngularJS) and I ran into a bit of trouble when I try to retrieve a single entity from my datastore.

My `ndb` model setup is:

```
class Ingredients(EndpointsModel):
    ingredient = ndb.StringProperty()

class Recipe(EndpointsModel):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    ingredients = ndb.StructuredProperty(Ingredients, repeated=True)
    instructions = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Here is the API method I've defined to retrieve the entity by `'title'`:

```
    @Recipe.method(request_fields=('title',), path='recipe/{title}',
                   http_method='GET', name='recipe.get')
    def get_recipe(self, recipe):
        if not recipe.from_datastore:
            raise endpoints.NotFoundException('Recipe not found.')
        return recipe
```

The API method works fine if I were to use `'id'` (helper methods provided by `EndpointsModel`) in place of `'title'` for the request fields. When I use `'title'`, however, I'm getting

> 404 Not Found
>
> {"error_message": "Recipe not found.","state": "APPLICATION_ERROR"}

Can anyone point out if I am missing something somewhere?

**NOTE**: See comments. The error in the question used to read

> 400 Bad Request
>
> {"error_message": "Error parsing ProtoRPC request (Unable to parse request content: Message RecipeProto_title is missing required field title)",
>   "state": "REQUEST_ERROR"}

but [@sentiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1998855/senitiki) was able to resolve this previous error.

Comment: How are you sending this request? Using the same code I'm getting the expected `NotFoundException`.

Comment: @bossylobster, thanks for responding. I'm sending the request from the API Explorer. I had inserted (using the insert method for the API) an entry into the datastore with the title 'Cookies' - I can see the entry in the datastore which means that it was inserted successfully. The error comes up when I try and use the above method and entering 'Cookies' into the title field on the API Explorer.

Comment: Are you missing the below part for your Recipe(EndpointsModel) : _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'ingredients', 'instructions')

Comment: @tony that won't matter since the `get_recipe` method is using `title`. However, as you noted, since no `id` property is set, the `UpdateFromKey` method would never be called and `from_datastore` would never have a chance to be set.

Comment: @senitiki What is the payload that gets sent/printed in the APIs explorer?

Comment: @bossylobster - Request on API Explorer is: 
GET http://localhost:10086/_ah/api/recipes/v1/recipe/Cookie
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

Comment: @bossylobster - so I decided to start over and thus I cleared my entire datastore, made an insert (confirmed it was successful) and now the response is 404 Not Found
- Show headers - {"error_message": "Recipe not found.","state": "APPLICATION_ERROR"}

Comment: @tony - even after adding that, I still get the 404 Not Found error I've stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `404` is expected. The "magic" of the `id` property is that it calls [UpdateFromKey](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L762).

This method tries to set an `ndb.Key` on the entity based on the request and then attempts to retrieve the entity stored with that key. If the entity exists, the values from the datastore are copied over to the entity parsed from the request and then the `_from_datastore` property is [set to `True`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L743).

By using `request_fields=('title',)`, you have a simple data property rather than an [`EndpointsAliasProperty`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/properties.py#L90) and so only the values are set. As a result, `_from_datastore` never gets set and your check

```
    if not recipe.from_datastore:
        raise endpoints.NotFoundException('Recipe not found.')
```

throws an `endpoints.NotFoundException` as expected.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. As I understand - please correct me if I'm wrong - for this to work, I will need to make the simple data property into an EndpointsAliasProperty? If yes, how would I go about doing that? Or is it that we can only use 'id' (helper methods provided by EndpointsModel) and we cannot use any of the properties that we define (in this case 'title')?

Comment: @senitiki Can you ask this as another SO question? I think it's perfectly valid for a new discussion.

Comment: @senitiki Where's that other question? :)

Comment: I've placed it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755372/cloud-endpoints-retrieving-a-single-entity-from-datastore-by-a-property-other