# Cloud Endpoints - Retrieving a single entity from datastore (by a property other than the helper methods provided by EndpointsModel)

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

This question completely follows on from a related question I had asked (and was answered) here: [Error when trying to retrieve a single entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647111/error-when-trying-to-retrieve-a-single-entity)

As I understand, to retrieve a single entity from the datastore using a property other than helper methods already provided (e.g. `'id'`) requires turning a simple data property into an `EndpointsAliasProperty`? If yes, how would I go about doing that? Or is it that we can only use `'id'` (helper methods provided by `EndpointsModel`) and we cannot use any of the properties that we define (in this case `'title'`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The distinction between the custom `EndpointsAliasProperty`s and one of the data properties you defined is how they are used. They are all used to create a `protorpc` message, and that message is then converted into an `EndpointsModel` with your custom data in it. **THIS** is where the magic happens.

Breaking it down into steps:

### 1. You specify your data

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel

class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
    my_attr = ndb.StringProperty()
```

### 2. You pick your fields for your method

```
class MyApi(...):

    @MyModel.method(request_fields=('id', 'my_attr'), ...)
    def my_method(self, my_model_entity):
        ...
```

### 3. A `protorpc` message class is defined from your fields

```
>>> request_message_class = MyModel.ProtoModel(fields=('id', 'my_attr'))
>>> request_message_class
<class '.MyModelProto_id_my_attr'>
>>> for field in request_message_class.all_fields():
...   print field.name, ':', field.variant
...
id : INT64
my_attr : STRING
```

This happens [every time](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L1262) a request is handled by a method decorated with `@MyModel.method`.

### 4. A request comes in your application and a message is created

Using the `protorpc` message class, a message instance is parsed from the JSON which gets passed along to your Endpoints [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) (which is created by `endpoints.api_server`).

When the request comes in to your `protorpc.remote.Service` it is [decoded](https://code.google.com/p/google-protorpc/source/browse/python/protorpc/wsgi/service.py?r=60e8f9831a0cefb30ea2024f4ae96f71b1b606b4#147):

```
>>> from protorpc import remote
>>> protocols = remote.Protocols.get_default()
>>> json_protocol = protocols.lookup_by_content_type('application/json')
>>> request_message = json_protocol.decode_message(
...      request_message_class,
...      '{"id": 123, "my_attr": "some-string"}'
... )
>>> request_message
<MyModelProto_id_my_attr
 id: 123
 my_attr: u'some-string'>
```

### 5. The `protorpc` message is [cast into a datastore model](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L1316)

```
entity = MyModel.FromMessage(request_message)
```

**THIS** is the step you really care about. The `FromMessage` class method (also provided as part of `EndpointsModel`) loops through all the fields

```
for field in sorted(request_message_class.all_fields(),
                    key=lambda field: field.number):
```

and for each field with a value set, turns the value into something to be added to the entity and separates based on whether the property is an `EndpointsAliasProperty` or not:

```
    if isinstance(value_property, EndpointsAliasProperty):
        alias_args.append((local_name, to_add))
    else:
        entity_kwargs[local_name] = to_add
```

After completing this loop, we have an ordered list `alias_args` of all key, value pairs and a dictionary `entity_kwargs` of the data attributes parsed from the message.

Using these, first a simple entity [is created](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L1162)

```
entity = MyModel(**entity_kwargs)
```

and then each of the alias property values are set **in order**:

```
for name, value in alias_args:
    setattr(entity, name, value)
```

---

The extended behavior happens in `setattr(entity, name, value)`. Since `EndpointsAliasProperty` is a subclass of [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), it is a descriptor and it has a `setter` which can perform some custom behavior **beyond** simply setting a value.

For example, the `id` property is [defined with](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L764):

```
@EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=IdSet, property_type=messages.IntegerField)
def id(self):
```

and the [`setter`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L745) performs operations beyond simply setting data:

```
def IdSet(self, value):
    self.UpdateFromKey(ndb.Key(self.__class__, value))
```

This particular method attempts to retrieve the entity stored in the datastore using the `id` and patch in any values from the datastore that were not included in the entity parsed from the request.

---

If you wanted to do this for a field like `my_attr`, you would need to construct a custom query which could retrieve the item with that unique `my_attr` value (or fail if not exactly one such entity exists).

This is problematic and you'd be better off using a unique field like the key or ID used to store the entity in the datastore.

The [keys with ancestors](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/keys_with_ancestors.html) sample gives a great example of creating your own custom properties.

If you **REALLY** insist on using `my_attr` to retrieve an entity, you could do so using a different property name (since `my_attr` is already used for the data property) such as `fromMyAttr`:

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
    def MyAttrSet(self, value):
        ...
    @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=MyAttrSet)
    def fromMyAttr(self):
        ...
```

Here, the `MyAttrSet` instance method would form the query:

```
    def MyAttrSet(self, value):
        query = MyModel.query(MyModel.my_attr == value)
        results = query.fetch(2)
```

reject results that aren't unique for `my_attr`:

```
        if len(results) == 0:
            raise endpoints.NotFoundException('Not found.')
        if len(results) == 2:
            raise endpoints.BadRequestException('Colliding results.')
```

and copy over the values for the already stored entity if we do find a unique one:

```
        matching_entity = results[0]
        self._CopyFromEntity(matching_entity)
        self._from_datastore = True
```

Comment: Thanks! I found this very helpful in getting a grip on what's happening with these properties. I'm not sure where "value_property" comes from in: "if isinstance(value_property,...)". And why is "in order" emphasized?

Comment: Also I wonder, as endpoints_proto_datastore seems to be a very practical way of dealing with the endpoints facility, why isn't there more traffic with this question?